# Use of Resources in Eval syntax

Tags: asp.net, eval

I'm wondering how I can use the Resources within the below Label - I'm not entirely sure.

The original line with a replacement "Yes" or "No":

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="someId" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("BooleanValue").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
```

What I believed I could do with the resources:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="someId" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("BooleanValue").ToString())) ? '<%$ Resources:language, Yes%>' : '<%$ Resources:language, No%>' %>'></asp:Label>
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got around this by declaring the variables in the code behind

```
protected string yes;
protected string no;
```

Then updating them once my page had loaded based on the culture the user set.

```
yes = language.ResourceManager.GetString("Yes",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
no = language.ResourceManager.GetString("No", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Then using those in the statement

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="someId" Text='<%# (bool)Eval("BooleanValue") == false ? no.ToString() : yes.ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
```